# Centering input field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this input field:

```html
<input alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" type="image" class="paypal">
```

I want to center it on the page, I tried using `text-align:center`, I tried to wrap it in a div set width to 100% and the margin to auto but it gets stretched in an ugly way, so how can I center it correctly?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Lo7w9vdp/ - and NEVER give anything in a form the name or ID submit if you are ever planning to submit something using script

Comment: Use a div to wrap and aling the input content like: `<div style="text-align:center"><input...></div>`

Comment: Thanks, it worked